# Proper use of header files

Tags: c

Coming up with errors for undefined references in main.c. This is because I have several files in this fashion:

```
main.c
{
    #include "somefile.h"
    somfunct() <--- undefined reference error
}

somefile.h
{
    somefunct() declaration
    ...
}

somefile.c
{
    #include "somefile.h"
    somefunct() definition
    ...
}
```

I am trying to use proper organization in that I use only declarations in the header files and define them in a separate file. After splitting up my code I get the undefined reference error because there is no link between somefile.h and somefile.c. **Even though main.c includes the somefile.h header file, there is nothing in somefile.h that explicitly mentions somefile.c**, so my functions are only partially defined. What is the proper way to take care of this problem? Many thanks. I hope this is clear let me know if not.

Comment: Don't put `#include` inside functions. Look at the preprocessed form (obtained with `gcc -C -E main.c > main.i`, then use a pager or editor to look inside `main.i`)

Comment: Your question is unclear. **Show your actual code** by editing your question. Read much more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). There are zillions of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) written in C, e.g. on http://github.com/. Download some of them (not too big) and study their source code as an example.

Comment: And understand that you could avoid having your `#include`d headers like `somefile.h` by copy and pasting your code at several places. But that is ugly and error-prone.

Comment: Also, show your compilation commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete and working example of your goal.

#### main.c

```
#include "somefile.h"

int main() {
    somefunc();
    return 0;
}
```

#### somefile.h

```
#ifndef RHURAC_SOMEFILE_H
#define RHURAC_SOMEFILE_H

void somefunc();

#endif
```

#### somefile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "somefile.h"

void somefunc() {
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

---

**example build ( gcc )**

```
gcc main.c somefile.c -o main
```

**output**

```
$ ./main 
hello
```

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear - my code is pseudo code. Using your suggestion is what i have and it still gives me the same error

Comment: @Rhurac if you get an error then you did not do exactly what Bill Lynch has shown

Comment: @Rhurac: does your actual code include the braces shown around the contents of the files in your pseudo-code?  It is very hard to debug your actual code when you don't show it and do use eccentric notations.  Please study how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
and then provide one.  Until then, Bill's done a good job showing what can be made to work — if you're still having trouble, you need to show us more precisely what that trouble is: actual source code, actual command line for compiling, and actual errors.