# How to organize Header files

Tags: c

Using header files in this way gives me the error "undefined reference to somefunc". What is the proper way to make sure `somefunc.c` is seen so this error doesn't occur? It seems simply including `somefile.h` in `main.c` isn't enough to see the definitions in `somefile.c`

**main.c**

```
#include "somefile.h"
int main() {
    somefunc();
return 0;
}
```

**somefile.h**

```
#ifndef SOMEFILE_H
#define SOMEFILE_H

void somefunc();

#endif
```

**somefile.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "somefile.h"

void somefunc() {
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting errors because this is the same manner in which they are used in tutorials and videos i've been viewing while looking for an answer. The code above is an answer given earlier but it is still has the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper use of header files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813896/proper-use-of-header-files)

Comment: Yes I asked this earlier in pseudo code and got irrelevant answers so I remade it with actual code to make it more clear

Comment: And you could not have edited that question - why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Undefined reference to `somefunc`* is a linker error, not a compiler error.

This means that, although when compiling `main.c` the header `somefile.h` is found, you are not compiling the file `somefile.c` together with `main.c`. So when linking occurs the linker is not able to find the implementation of `somefunc` in any object file to resolve the call from `main()`.

If you are using GCC or Clang just compile both source files to your command, eg

```
gcc somefunc.c main.c -o output
```

If you are using an IDE instead, make sure that `somefile.c` is compiled together with `main.c` when building the application.

Comment: Thank you so so much this has been giving me a headache for hours now. Exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to differentiate between linker errors and compiler errors?

Comment: Generally, compiler errors reference the source with line number, linker errors usually complain with the telltale "undefined reference", without pointing to source code (other than saying what module made a call to the missing function

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be a problem with the header file.

This appears to be a problem in linking, which depends on how you build the project. If you use an IDE, it means that somefile.c is not included in the project. If you're using make and a makefile, it means that somefile.c is not listed in the makefile, or at least not included for the linker. If you're building at the command line (not using make or some build tool, but using gcc), then you're not including somefile.c in the command.

The undefined reference error means the linker couldn't find the code in somefile.c, because the linker didn't know to include it.